# Dart/vscode: enforce function argument types when passing function itself as an argument to constructor

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart

As the subject suggests, how does one enforce function argument types in editor (say VSCode) when the function itself is passed as an argument to a class constructor? This goes for complex types. In the simple example below, vscode linter doesn't hiccup when calling the passed add() function with incorrect (int) argument rather than the correct (String) argument:

```
class ChildClass {

   final Function add;
   ChildClass(this.add);

   ...
   add('this is a string');  <---- HOW TO ENFORCE STRING ARGUMENT TYPE?
   add(5); <----- EDITOR (VSCODE) should hiccup currently doesn't
}

class ParentClass {
  int _add(String text) {   <--- ARGUMENT OF TYPE STRING
    // some code
  }

  final childClass = ChildClass(_add);  <-- pass add() as argument to ChildClass ctor

}
```

Not sure if this is a vscode linter question or a dart question or both. Thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify function types inline

```
class ChildClass {

   final int Function(String text) add;
```

or as typedef

```
typedef AddFn = int Function(string text);

class ChildClass {

   final AddFn add;
```

See also

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/generic-function-type-alias.md
- https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs